# Whatsapp Online Status Inquiry

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

This question might have already been answered so sorry in advance.
My question is: If I am using Whatsapp, it would obviously show me as online but what if I have the application open but my screen timed-out/turned-off, will it still show me as online? Or will it show as last seen (time before screen time-out)? Will it only show as online when I'm in the app actively using it, or will it show as online until I close it (go to home screen or close the app)?
Thank you.

Comment: I think it's when you're actively using the app, or when you briefly quite the app (using the home button)

Answer (score 0):

WhatsApp will only show you as online when you're in the app. In fact - even if you reply to a message from **in-notification**, you still won't be shown as online.